# 配列のほしいデータのみを取り出す

Tags: php, html, laravel

日付のみのデータを配列から取りたいのですがうまくいきません。

```
<?php var_dump($date->date); ?>
```

の結果が

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Carbon)[1310]
  public 'date' => string '2019-03-19 16:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Asia/Tokyo' (length=10)
```

でした。この`'date' => string '2019-03-19 16:00:00.000000' (length=26)`の部分を取り、のちにバリデーションに使用しようと思っています。

どうすればとれるでしょうか？

・環境
laravel5.6
php7.1.27

追記：
他の記入箇所でもその配列を使用するためなるべく同じやり方に統一させたいという意向です。

Comment: 本当に「配列からの要素を取り出す」のが目的でしょうか？もし日付部分を取得したいのであれば、はじめから(日付部分を返す)適切なメソッドを呼び出した方がスマートな気がします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

丁度いい記事がありました。質問のデータが「配列」だと考えているのは、誤解ですね。
DateTimeクラスのオブジェクトを構成するプロパティを目視できるように表示したものです。

[Why can't I access DateTime->date in PHP's DateTime class? Is it a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14084222/9014308)

> PHPのDateTimeクラスでDateTime-> dateにアクセスできないのはなぜですか？それはバグですか？
>
> `DateTime`クラスを使用して、次のコードを実行しようとした場合：
>
> ```
> $mydate = new DateTime();
> echo $mydate->date;
> ```
>
> このエラーメッセージが表示されます
>
> ```
> Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date...
> ```
>
> 変数`$mydate`に対して`var_dump()`を実行すると、このプロパティが存在し、一般にアクセス可能であることが明確に示されるため、これは意味がありません。
>
> ```
> var_dump($mydate);
>
> object(DateTime)[1]
>   public 'date' => string '2012-12-29 17:19:25' (length=19)
>   public 'timezone_type' => int 3
>   public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
> ```
>
> これはPHPのバグですか？それとも私は何か問題がありますか？私はPHP 5.4.3を使用しています。

それに対しての答えがこれです。

> これは[既知の問題](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382)です。
>
> 利用可能な日付は、実際には `var_dump()` のサポートによる副作用です。 - derick@php.net
>
> 何らかの理由で、あなたはそのプロパティにアクセスすることはできないが、とにかく `var_dump` はそれを表示します。本当にその形式で日付を取得したい場合は、[`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) 関数を使用してください。
>
> ```
> echo $mydate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
> ```

---

その上で質問のようにマイクロ秒まで文字列にしたいのであれば、`u` を使うことになるでしょう。
[PHPでマイクロ秒精度のDateTimeを生成する際の注意点](http://ezolab-blog.net/blog-entry-22.html)

> ```
> <?php
> // 現在日時を生成
> $now = new \DateTime();
> // 出力
> echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
> ?>
> ```

上記の結果例

> ```
> 2015-10-24 02:37:31.000000
> ```

さらに関連して版数による注意事項があるようです。
[PHP 7.2.0からDateTimeでミリ秒表示するときの丸め処理が変わった話](https://hnw.hatenablog.com/entry/20180401)